# Has WSO2 WSF/CPP been pre-hardened or checked against the NVD database?

Tags: wso2, wsh

We are preparing a deployment of our product to our customer and are currently going through the hardening process. Can anyone tell me if WSO2 WSF/CPP has been hardened or checked against the [NVD](http://nvd.nist.gov/) database?

Thank you for your help

Eugene